# insert an object as identic document into mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have an object that i like to store into mongo. My issue is that i want to store the object's attributes as fields of the document, and not the whole object as a single field.

```
obj ={attA:x, attB:y} ;   
MyCol.insert({obj});
```

After inserting the object I get this:

```
{_id:xxxx, obj:{attA, attB}}
```

Rather I'm looking for this result

```
{_id:xxx, attA:x, attB:y}
```

I tried with a JSON.stringify but didn't work.  What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in this way:

`MyCol.insert(obj);`

Note, in ES6 creating object using syntax `{obj}`, is the same as `{obj:obj}`.